# After browser refresh I can't emit to specific client anymore?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My code looks something like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    player.on('updatePlayer', function(err, result) {
        if(result) {
            console.log("UPDATING PLAYER");
            io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('updatePlayer', { player: player });
        }
    });
}
```

When I first start the server and load the website everything works fine. If I do an action that triggers the "updatePlayer" event my console looks like this:

```
UPDATING PLAYER
debug - websocket writing 5:::{DATA IM SENDING}
```

After I refresh the page, or close it and reload again I only get:

```
UPDATING PLAYER
```

Anyone has any idea why the socket doesn't emit anything at all?
It seems to ignore

```
io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('updatePlayer', { player: player });
```

Comment: What is `player`? How do you initialize it?

Comment: I also initialize it in the sockets.on('connection') scope. But I don't see how that matters. Shouldn't the socket.emit be at least called? It's just totally blank in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because when you first visit the page after server start, you register `updatePlayer` event, and this callback "remembers" the current `socket` object.

Then you reload the page, that `updatePlayer` event fires, and its callback tries to access `socket` that was "remembered". That `socket` refers to your previous connection that is lost after page reload. That's why it can't send the message.

To solve this problem you have to declare *all* the variables, that connected somehow with `player` object, inside `io.sockets.on('connection')` callback.

Comment: It was indeed a scope problem after all. My actual code was much longer then what I posted.